How to implement FMX TSelection having 8 grab handles just like Delphi IDE?
TSelection has 4 handles for re-sizing whereas the Delphi IDE will provide 8 (so that you can resize in 1 direction only) instead of having to resize at the corners (which affect both width and height).

Is there a way to extend TSelection to do the same?
Thank you.

Yes there is.  If you look into the included source code of TSelection (may not be included in Community Edition) you will see that it determines if your mouse is over one of the selection points using GetHandleForPoint function and then uses specific transform procedure based on which GrabHandle was used. So it probably would not be to hard to modify the GetHandleForPoint to detect if the mouse is over any of the four additional grab points and write four additional transform procedures which would modify just one edge at the time. ...

... You would also need to make small modification to Paint method to draw those four additional handles.

oh, sounds like a fair bit of work! I just wonder since they already did it for IDE, why not just release it.  It would also have been useful for the component to have an OnGrabHandle event to show us which handle is being moused over or dragged.

@SilverWarior The Community Edition includes source codes.

@PeterJones First thing you need to know is that Delphi IDE is based on VCL framework and not FMX framework. So even when you are designing FMX application the form designer is still based on VCL. That is why some VCL components doesn't look the same at design-time as they do at runtime. Another thing you should know is that in Delphi IDE those grab handles are part of form designer while with TSelection the grab handles are part of TSelection itself.

@PhilipJ.Rayment Yes I know Community Edition does include some source code but as far as I know it does so in more limited form.

@SilverWarior, I can't say for sure, but my understanding is that the CE version is identical to the Professional edition, apart from the licence.  And as far as this question is concerned, the source code for FMX's Objects unit—that has TSelection—is included.

As this question wasn't tagged with firemonkey and the VCL has a TSelection (which I now see is a totally different type), and the IDE uses VCL controls, I didn't realise that it was talking about the FMX one.  This question should have a firemonkey tag.

yes, it is for FMX. I've updated the tag. thank you.

@SilverWarior good point that Delphi IDE is based on VCL. but they also never released this 8-handle component to VCL..

Does anyone want to try give a start to over-riding the component to provide for a) 8 handles - which means can stretch in one direction only without having to pull the corner handle b) sensitive to .Align (eg, if Top, then can only pull down the bottom handle)...

@PeterJones Unfortunately I don't have much time for a next few days. Maybe I'll give it a crack during the weekend. But I don't promise anything.

@PeterJones "Does anyone want to try give a start to ..." - that is outside the scope of this question, and of this site in general. You asked a question, and an answer was given (as a comment, though). TSelection does not natively support what you want, but you can try extending it yourself. If you run into trouble doing that, then feel free to ask a new question about that problem. But don't just ask people to write the code for you. Now, if SilverWarior wants to expand his comment in a full answer with an example, that would be their choice ...

@RemyLebeau Maybe my original question was not phrased well. It could have been "How to implement..."  when I said "does anyone want to try to give a start", I'm not asking anyone to write the full component code, the start meant some basic skeleton like how to override the 2 procedures mentioned, which will allow the rest of us to contribute. So for experts, maybe it seems obvious how to implement based on the above, but for the rest of us who have not inherited visual components, it is not so obvious.  So my question is really phrased as if one has time, then "start" with a basic structure.

I have edited my question to better reflect my original intention, which was not so much "Is it possible to do that" - because we all know Delphi can do that.  Question should be "how to do that..." I will take care to phrase my question more thoughtfully in future. Thank you for the reminder.

TSelection looks like it makes use of the TSelectionPoint control for the four handles.  But it doesn't.  Also TSelection defines an enumerated type for the four handles, which I think would make it hard to create a descendant with eight handles.
So my (untested) suggestion is to make a new control from scratch, basing it on a TRectangle to draw the outline, and add eight TSelectionPoint controls to it.  I think you'd need to override TRectangle.SetBounds to update the positions of the handles when the size of the TRectangle changes, and handle the TSelectionPoint's OnTrack event to respond to a user dragging the handles.

Thanks for trying. I'm hoping to descend from TSelection instead of writing a new one.
